# Links between "productive" and "completely productive" sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computer-science, computability

In a computability course I met the two following notions :

> A set $B$ is "completely productive" if there exists a total computable function $f$ such that : $\forall x \in \mathbb N \ (f(x) \in \overline B \Leftrightarrow f(x) \in \mathcal W_x)$.

and

> A set $B$ is "productive" if there exists a total computable function $f$ such that : $\forall x \in \mathbb N \ (\mathcal W_x \subseteq B \Rightarrow f(x) \in B\setminus\mathcal W_x)$.

I was wondering what were the links between these two notions ? I noticed that if we consider the complement of the halting set $\mathcal K$, it was both "completely productive" and "productive". For instance, is one of the notion stronger than the other one ?

Thanks in advance !

*Edit* : The result of equivalence between these two notions has been proved by Myhill (Rogers, *theory of recursive functions and effective computability*) !

Comment: I don't know who the equivalence is due to. I just checked my copy of Rogers and found the theorem there, but it's not attributed to anybody.  Maybe you have a later edition of Rogers and he added the attribution in that edition?  In my copy, the *previous* theorem in the section is attributed to Myhill, and the techniques are similar. I don't know if Rogers just accidentally omitted the attribution, or if the theorem is due to someone other than Myhill.

Comment: @MitchellSpector In my edition (1987) it was in the exercises section of chapter 7 (the 52-th) !

Comment: Thank you!  I hadn't see that exercise.  I've added the attribution to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two notions ("productive" and "completely productive") are equivalent.  (Edit: @Maman has pointed out that this equivalence to due to Myhill, according to Rogers' recursion theory book.)

@AndreasBlass showed in his answer that completely productive implies productive.

For the other direction, let $B$ be productive, with $f$ a recursive function satisfying the defining property $$\forall x (W_x \subseteq B \Rightarrow f(x) \in B\setminus W_x).$$

Use the recursion theorem to find a recursive function $g$ such that, for all $x,$
$$W_{g(x)} = \begin{cases}
\{f(g(x))\},&\text{ if }f(g(x))\in W_x,\\
\emptyset,&\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

(The recursion theorem can be applied because an r.e. index for the set defined by $$\begin{cases}
\{f(y)\},&\text{ if }f(y)\in W_x,\\
\emptyset,&\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$ can be computed uniformly in $x$ and $y.$ Here's how to enumerate that set: Just compute $f(y)$ and then start enumerating $W_x.$ Check each value enumerated; if $f(y)$ ever shows up in the enumeration of $W_x,$ output $f(y)$ and halt.  If it never shows up, the algorithm will never halt and we'll output nothing at all.)

We claim that the composition $f\circ g$ witnesses that $B$ is completely productive:

For any $x,$ if $f(g(x))\not\in W_x,$ then $W_{g(x)}=\emptyset\subseteq B,$ and so, using the fact that $f$ witnesses the productiveness of $B,$ we have that $f(g(x))\in B\setminus W_{g(x)},$ so $f(g(x)\in B.$

Conversely, if $f(g(x))\in W_x,$ then $W_{g(x)} = \{f(g(x))\},$ so $f(g(x))\in W_{g(x)}.$ Using once again the fact that $f$ is a witness to the productiveness of $B,$ we can conclude that $W_{g(x)}\not\subseteq B.$ But $W_{g(x)} = \{f(g(x))\},$ so it follows that $f(g(x))\not\in B.$

Comment: Nice answer, thank you ! When you write "the recursion theorem" is it equivalent to "the smn theorem" ?

Comment: @Maman  The recursion theorem is different from the *s-m-n* theorem. The simplest form of the recursion theorem states that for any recursive function $h$ of one variable, there exists an index $e$ such that $\varphi_e$ and $\varphi_{h(e)}$ are the same partial recursive function; it follows that $W_e=W_{h(e)}.$ The answer above uses a parametrized version: for any recursive function $h$ of two variables, there exists a recursive function $g$ of one variable such that for all $x,$ $W_{g(x)}=W_{h(g(x),x)}.$

Comment: Oh ok I guess it is sometimes called the fixed point theorem by Kleene ! I think I get it now !

Comment: Yes, that’s the same thing. But it’s not really a fixed-point theorem, since you don’t get $h(e)=e.$

Answer (score 2):

As the terminology suggests, any completely productive set is productive. To prove it, let $B$ be completely productive, and let $f$ be as required in the definition. I claim that  the same  $f$ also witnesses that $B$ is productive. Indeed, if $W_x\subseteq B$, then the statements $f(x)\in\overline B$ and $f(x)\in W_x$ can't both be true. So, by our choice of $f$, they must both be false. That is, $f(x)\in B-W_x$.

Comment: Indeed thank you !